How can these different Snowflake query behaviors for "=" versus "IN" be explained?
Why does Query 1 return many rows while Query 2 returns zero rows?
Query 1:
SELECT distinct col_a, col_b
    FROM t
    WHERE
        col_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(col_timestamp ) FROM t)
        AND col_c = col_c

Query 2:
SELECT distinct col_a, col_b
    FROM t
    WHERE
        col_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(col_timestamp ) FROM t)
        AND col_c IN (col_c)


can you pls add some sample data ?

Query 1: col_c = col_c is true for all rows that are not NULL, so this returns all rows where col_c is not NULL.
Query 2: col_c IN (col_c) attempts to check if col_c is within a list containing itself. However, due to Snowflake's scoping rules, the condition fails for all rows, resulting in zero rows returned.

This SQL is very confused, lets make some example data to show the confusion.
with t(col_a, col_b, col_c,col_timestamp) as (
    select * from values 
        (1,10,100, 1000),
        (1,10,100, 900),
        (1,10,null, 1000),
        (2,20,200, 2000),
        (2,20,200, 1900),
        (2,20,null, 2000)   
)
SELECT col_a, 
    col_b,
    col_c
FROM t
WHERE col_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(col_timestamp ) FROM t)
 and col_c = col_c

gives:



COL_A
COL_B
COL_C




2
20
200



but I suspect you really want to find the latest PER col_c thus the SQL would make more sense like:
with t(col_a, col_b, col_c,col_timestamp) as (
    select * from values 
        (1,10,100, 1000),
        (1,10,100, 900),
        (1,10,null, 1000),
        (2,20,200, 2000),
        (2,20,200, 1900),
        (2,20,null, 2000)   
)
SELECT col_a, 
    col_b,
    col_c
FROM t as t
WHERE t.col_timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(tt.col_timestamp ) 
    FROM t as tt 
    WHERE t.col_c = tt.col_c
)

which gives:

But if you change your timestamp data to have duplicates like:
with t(col_a, col_b, col_c,col_timestamp) as (
    select * from values 
        (1,10,100, 1000),
        (1,10,100, 900),
        (1,10,null, 1000),
        (2,20,200, 2000),
        (2,20,200, 2000),
        (2,20,null, 2000)   
)

Now you get double 2,20 data, thus the DISTINCT clause

But really you could be doing what you intend. But the base SQL used to show this "strange behavour" in of itself, is strange.
